# Алгоритм как понять что квадрат находится внутри любой фигуры? (lisp)

Tags: lisp, autocad

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имею все точки заданной фигуры и все точки одного из квадратов. Фигура не обязательно выпукла. Пишу так как не знаю какой алгоритм будет эффективен для любого вида фигур.
Пишу на Lisp в связке с Autocad

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: Можно попробовать считать площадь ребра, по нему определять квадрат, а если потом вернёшься в ту же полосу, то просто переразбивать на меньшие, если это необходимо.

Comment: А какая вообще цель-то?